# Foreach loop in java for Dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, for-loop

I want to go through every items in a dictionary in java. to clarify what I want to do, this is the C# code

```
Dictionary<string, Label> LableList = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Label> z in LabelList);
```

I don't know how to do this is java, for example I did this

```
for(Object z: dic)
```

but it says it's not iterable. Please advise......

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a `Map<String, Label>` which is the Java built-in dictionary structure.  Java doesn't let you iterate directly over a `Map` (i.e. it doesn't implement `Iterable`) because it would be ambiguous what you're actually iterating over.

It's just a matter of choosing to iterate through the keys, values or entries (both).

e.g.

```
Map<String, Label> map = new HashMap<String, Label>();
//...

for ( String key : map.keySet() ) {
}

for ( Label value : map.values() ) {
}

for ( Map.Entry<String, Label> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Label value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Your C# code seems to be the same as iterating over the entries (the last example).

Comment: This is how I define it:
Dictionary <String, Label> dic = null;
I don't know anything about Map... Is it some kind of dictionary?

Comment: @Daniel Reading the javadoc would tell you `NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class.`, so you should be using one of the new map classes. You probably want a `HashMap` - that also implements the new functions you need for iterable to work

Comment: Amazing, I had long since forgotten that Hashtable had a Dictionary superclass.

Comment: @Mark Yeah I had to look it up as well, my first instinct was "Wait Java doesn't even have a Dictionary what the hell are you doing?". Dictionary was superseded in 1.2 (just to show how ancient that is: 1.2 was the first version where Sun's JVM included a JIT)

Answer (score 6):

`java.util.Map` is the Dictionary equvivalent and below is an example on how you can iterate through each entry

```
for(Map.Entry<K, V> e : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(e.getKey()+": "+e.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use this:

```
for (String key : LableList.keys()) {
    Label value = LableList.get(key);

    // do what you wish with key and value here
}
```

In Java however, a better bet is to not use Dictionary as you would in .NET but to use one of the Map subclasses, e.g. HashMap. You can iterate through one of these like this:

```
for (Entry<String, Label> e : myMap.entrySet()) {
    // Do what you wish with e.getKey() and e.getValue()
}
```

You are also advised against using Dictionary in the official javadoc.

Comment: Dictionary.keys() returns an Enumeration which does not implement Iterable and thus cannot be used in the foreach loop. Your code will not compile.

Comment: So either my Eclipse compiler is broken (which shows and error), or we're not talking about the same thing. (Not that Dictionary matters in any way)

Comment: what's your Java version?

Comment: Java 1.6.0_45, with default compliance level. Maybe you meant .keySet() instead of .keys()? .keySet is only implemented when the collection also implements Map (which Dictionary doesn't, but eg. Properties does).

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to add the contents of one HashMap (a) into another HashMap (b).

I found it simple to iterate through HashMap a this way:

```
a.forEach((k, v) -> b.put(k, v));
```

You can manipulate my example to do what ever you want on the other side of "->".

Note that this is a Lambda expression, and that you would have to use Java 1.8 (Java 8) or later for this to work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For people wondering how you truly iterate over a dictionary if you cannot use a Map for example using SeviceReferences in Java:

**Java 8+**

```
  dict.keys().asIterator().forEachRemaining((key -> {
         value = dict.get(key);

         //your code here using the key/value pair.
  });
```