# Iterate Dictionary in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I've a dictionary in java:

```
protected Dictionary<String, Object> objects;
```

Now I want to get the keys of the dictionary, so that I can get the value of the key with get() in a for loop:

```
for (final String key : this.objects) {
    final Object value = this.objects.get(key);
```

But this doesn't work. :(
Any idea?

Thx
Thomas

PS: I need the key & the value both in a variable.

Comment: The same question is answered in the following link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371667/foreach-loop-in-java-for-dictionary

Comment: For starters, avoid using `Dictionary`; it's a legacy class. Use `HashMap` instead.

Comment: The difference in performance between HashMap and Dictionary is relevant for C#, NOT for Java. They're completely different languages, in Java we've been using HashMap for over 15 years, and that's recommended over Dictionary. Dictionary doesn't even implement the Map interface, it's way obsolete.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First things first. The `Dictionary` class is way, way obsolete. You should be using a `Map` instead:

```
protected Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Once that's fixed, I think this is what you meant:

```
for (String key : objects.keySet()) {
    // use the key here
}
```

If you intend to iterate over both keys and values, it's [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap) to do this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : objects.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object val = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: He's not using a `Map` but a `Dictionary`... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html#keys%28%29... It may or may not be better to use a `Map` depending on what he's trying to do but it's an important distinction

Comment: @StormeHawke yep, I just realized that. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: But a Map is quit slow, if you are using a lot of objects (100,000 or more)

Comment: @ThomasFlynn where did you hear such a thing? that's not correct. `Dictionary` is so obsolete that it uses `Enumeration` instead of `Iterator` for iterating over its entries. People have been using classes implementing `Map` for more than a decade without complaining of bad performance. And besides, 100.000 objects is a very small number of objects

Comment: So what should I use?

Comment: @ThomasFlynn that link is for C# !!!, this question is about Java, the referenced data structures are not comparable, _at all_. Use `Map` as I suggested, that's the way to go in Java

Comment: @ThomasFlynn without question use `Map`, and its main implementor, `HashMap`.  If you ever need to preserve the order in which the contents are added, use `LinkedHashMap`. Unless you're writing multithreaded programs, that is all you'll ever need to store data this way

Answer (score 9):

If you have to use a dictionary (for example osgi felix framework ManagedService) then the following works..

```
public void updated(Dictionary<String, ?> dictionary) 
    throws ConfigurationException {

    if(dictionary == null) {
        System.out.println("dict is null");
    } else {
        Enumeration<String> e = dictionary.keys();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String k = e.nextElement();
            System.out.println(k + ": " + dictionary.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.Map` is the Dictionary equvivalent and below is an example on how you can iterate through each entry

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//...

for ( String key : map.keySet() ) {
}

for ( Object value : map.values() ) {
}

for ( Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values as

```
for(final String key : this.objects.keys()){
  final Object value = this.objects.get(key);
}
```