# Iterate Through Properties in OSGi Configuration

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I'm using OSGi ConfigurationAdmin to return a list of configurations:

```
Configuration[] configurations = configAdmin.listConfigurations(null);
```

I can then iterate through that list to get the Persistent IDs (group of configuration properties):

```
for (Configuration configuration : configurations) {
    System.out.println(configuration.getPid());
}
```

How do i now iterate through the properties in each PID/Configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Iterate Dictionary in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280373/iterate-dictionary-in-java). See answer that states:

> If you have to use a dictionary (for example osgi felix framework
>   ManagedService) then the following works...

I ended up using an iterator, as described there. Interestingly, that answer pertains to OSGi's use of Dictionary, which is also what raised the question for me.